# android-asycn-http: Never send the http request

Tags: java, android, httpclient, android-async-http

I'm using `android-async-http 1.4.5`, but I found it never calls my server, here's my code :

```
public class HttpUtils {
  private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

  public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    params.setUseJsonStreamer(true);
    client.get(url, params, responseHandler);
  }

  public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    params.setUseJsonStreamer(true);
    Log.i("URL", url);
    client.post(url, params, responseHandler);
  }
}
```

Here's how I define my handler:

```
public abstract class JsonResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
  private static final String TAG = "JSON_RESPONSE_HANDLER";


  public abstract void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject jsonObject);

  public abstract void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject jsonObject);

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
    Log.i(TAG, "on success");
    onSuccess(statusCode, headers, parseObject(responseBody));
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
    Log.i(TAG, "on failure");
    onFailure(statusCode, headers, parseObject(responseBody));
  }

  private JSONObject parseObject(byte[] response) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    try {
      String json = new String(response, "UTF-8");
      jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObj;
  }
}
```

After some debug work, I found my code actually execute `client.post(...)`, but my server didn't receive any call from it.

### EDIT

Here's how I use it in my test case :

```
public class VerifyCodeTest extends TestCase {

  private static final String TAG  ="VERIFY_CODE_TEST";

  public void testGetVerifyCode(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Hello World");

    VerifyCodeTransaction vc= new VerifyCodeTransaction("167xxxx137");
    vc.execute(new JsonResponseHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject jsonObject) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SUCCESS");
        Log.i(TAG, jsonObject.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject jsonObject) {
        Log.i(TAG, "FAILURE");
        Log.i(TAG, jsonObject.toString());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: How can you tell your server didn't get the request? Also, have you tried to debug by using `curl` or `httpie` just to confirm the url / params are correct?

Comment: @user2713030 , I'm sure the server didn't get the request because I'm developing the server at the same time(on another machine). The url is correct, I've tested it with `postman`.

Comment: Do you know what type or object you're expecting in the response? I faced something similar in the past. I overrode `onSuccess(..., JSONObject response)`, and received nothing, but it worked with `onSuccess(..., JSONArray response)`. Same for `JSONObject` vs `String`.

Comment: The problem is, `client.post()` doesn't send the request to server, so weird! Plus, I'm using it from a android test project.

Comment: Is your client on device or emulstor?

Comment: @greenapps, I'm using an `android 4.3` device.

Comment: You tested 'it' with postman. But that was postman on another pc. Not on your device i think. Try that url in a browser on the device to see if you get a connection.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you encounter this problem only in your TestCase or also in your App. I think the library doesn't work well for unit tests!! source:https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/321

i had a similar problem with the library in the past, i solved it by compiling the library from the source code in github repo

Maybe it's better that you use the latest version of the library :)